# Is it okay to use "go to" from a catch statement

Tags: c++, try-catch, goto

Everything I have ever been told is that go to's are evil and stay away from them, but I think they may help me here (?). I would like to provide the user an option to restart the application when an exception is caught and am having a bit of trouble wrapping my head around what to do...

My application will be monitored by another process, but there are some exceptions where I want to the user to be able to decide what to do without returning control to the calling process.

Is something like this "acceptable"? Any other suggestions?

Thanks so much!

```
int main(){

    initialize:
       try{
        //do things
       }
       catch(...)
       {
          cout<<"Would you like to try initializing again?"<<endl;

          //if yes
            goto initialize;

          //if not
          abort(); //or something...
        }

return 0;
}
```

Comment: This furious hatred of goto is bizarre. I'm guessing it's the same people who scream premature optimization on every post about optimization.

Comment: @Inverse: It's not our fault that 95% of the posts about optimization are premature (i.e., before the "measure" in "measure, optimize, measure"). But isn't that a *bit* OT? ;-)

Answer (score 9):

Why not like this?

```
while(true){
  //Do stuff
  if(exit){
    break;
  }
}
```

or

```
continue = true;
do{
  //Do stuff
  if(exit){
    continue = false;
  }
}while(continue);
```

Comment: How would you get back into the while loop if needed? Also, what are the implications on try/catch? I'm planning on catching many different types of exceptions and need to give the user options on what to do...

Comment: @Jon, if you need to jump in and out of the loop, then you have to seperate it in it's own function, then just call the function when you need it.

Comment: @Briedis I'd still like the function/loop to be in a try block. If I call the function/loop again from inside the catch, it won't be in a try anymore, right?

Comment: @Jon, try-catch doesn't care what you call within it, it just catches exceptions, so you can put in try-catch function calls, loops, whatever you want. But in my opinion, you should only surround the minimal block of code that can throw the exception.

Comment: I don't like the `break` in the first example. (It's a poorly disguised `goto`.) The second example is a bit better, but looks rather contrived, what with using that `continue` flag (bad boy, a keyword as identifier) in three places when `return`ing from an encapsuling function would do nicely.

Answer (score 6):

you could try :

```
int main()
{
     while(true)
     {
          try
          {
               program();
          }
          catch(std::exception& e)
          {
               std::cout << "Start again?" << std::endl;
               //Check ...
               if(!go_on)
                    break;
          }
     }
     return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Yes, technically it is okay, but usual "goto considered harmful" considerations apply.

Comment: goto is never ok - avoid it like the plague.  It will bite you when you have a bug later on.  Don't ever consider it even.

Comment: @Paul: Do you have a comparison of how many people plague killed and how many people use of `goto` killed?

Comment: `goto` is OK. It is the simplest possible flow control mechanism, and finding the jump target is simpler than pretty much any other. If it avoids repetition, then there is no problem with it; in C++, it is pretty much impossible to tie yourself up in knots using `goto` because you can't actually go anywhere so confusingly far enough away that it might cause a problem that you don't have already.

Comment: Watch which answer comes out on top in a month.  If there are enough of you still using goto to bump up your answer I will be disappointed.

Comment: Seconded. Geez, half a decade of computing, and people still defend `goto` as a valid coding practice. No wonder so much software still sucks in spades.

Comment: @sharptooth: The "usual 'goto considered harmful' considerations" have only one thing to say: `goto` is **not** "okay". ;-)

Comment: *sticks fingers in ears* I HATE GOTO LALALALALALALA

Answer (score 5):

A `goto` can *always* be avoided, giving cleaner code.

By the way, the same goes for `break`s outside a `switch`. The `continue` keyword is marginally less condemnable, because at least it honors the enclosing loop's condition.

It is important to catch exceptions at the right place - where you can handle the condition most effectively.

And if a condition turns out to be inconvenient (like the "try again?" in my case), consider negating it ("fail?") for cleaner structure.

```
// Tries until successful, or user interaction demands failure.
bool initialize() {
    for ( ;; ) {
        try {
            // init code
            return true;
        }
        catch ( ... ) {
            cout << "Init Failed. Fail Program?" << endl;
            if ( yes ) {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
}

int main() {
    if ( ! initialize() ) {
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    // rest of program
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

**Notes:** This does not use `goto` or `break`, and it does not recurse (*especially* not from within a `catch` block).

Comment: An early return is just a goto in disguise? Just kidding!

Comment: @Bo Persson: Try drawing a Nassi-Shneiderman diagram of my early return vs. the `break` solutions I critizised as gotos in disguise. You will see the difference: An early return leaves the whole block, while a break tries to jump to a different position in the block. No kidding. ;-)

Answer (score 2):

The original quote was (I believe) "uncontrolled use of goto considered harmful". Gotos can be useful, but must be used in a controlled fashion. There is one programming technique, to create reentrant subroutines, dependent on the state of the program or data, that positively demands directed jumps. Though this technique may well be considered old fashioned, I understand that it is still used, but is hidden by more modern language and compiler features. The point of the control is that you must stop and ask yourself, not just "is there a more structured way of doing the same thing" - @Justin - but also "under what specific conditions will I use a goto?" Being convenient is probably not a sufficient condition to use it, without this wider answer.

Comment: The catch is that some of us have been programming for decades, without finding those "specific conditions" even once. They must be very rare!

Comment: The approach that used this approach substantially was Jackson Structured Programming. The technique was to design independent, communicating programs, and then "invert" one of the programs to become a reentrant, stateful series of subroutines. This could only be done by writing the called program with loop free code - and the way to derive loop free code was to replace loop constructs with gotos. This was done automatically by the preprocessor for (at least) C, Pascal, and Cobol. This approach was extensively used in the UK and Scandinavia, in many private, government and military projects.

Comment: Ok, using machine generated code with gotos is similar to the compiler generating jmp for break and continue. I have just never written any gotos myself, and not even been close.

Answer (score 1):

Normal way of handling exceptions is at the place where you can do something. It is obvious that the place you are trying to handle them is not right, since you have to use goto.

So, something like this :

```
void mainLoop() // get user settings, process, etc
{
   try
   {
     // 1) get user settings
     // 2) process data
     // 3) inform of the result
   }
   catch( const exception_type & e)
   {
     // inform of the error
   }      
}

int main()
{
  try
  {
    while(true)
      mainLoop();
  }
  catch(...)
  {
    std::cout<<"an unknown exception caught... aborting() " << std::endl;
  }
}
```

Comment: but if you restart the mainLoop() it will be outside of a try block, will it not?

Comment: @Jon Right, I fixed the example

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Based on [the C++ draft Standard](https://eel.is/c++draft/except):

> goto statement can be used to transfer control out of a try block or
> handler.

For example, this code is legal:

```
lab:  try {
  T1 t1;
  try {
    T2 t2;
    if (condition)
      goto lab;
    } catch(...) { /* handler 2 */ }
  } catch(...) { /* handler 1 */ }
```

However, it is important to mention that:

> When this happens, each variable declared in the try block will be destroyed in the context that directly contains its declaration.

Answer (score 0):

I really like this use of `goto`.  As long as it's kept in a very small and local scope, it really avoids the spaghetti that everyone fears and actually makes things clearer than the alternatives.

```
try_again:
try {
    do_something();
} catch (const std::exception& e) {
    std::cerr << e.what() << std::endl;
    goto try_again;
}
```

If I write the logic in other ways, I add more variables, more logic, more lines, more indenting.  I don't like this while loop because our variable name doesn't make sense for the first pass, and we pollute our business logic by adding conditions to exit the loop.

```
bool try_again = true;
while(try_again) {
    try {
        do_something();
        try_again = false;
    } catch( const std::exception& e) {
        std::cerr << e.what() << std::endl;
    }
}
```

A `do`/`while` loop makes it a little better: we need to do something to our special variable in the error handling to try again.  But we still have extra variables, logic, and nesting.  Also, `do`/`whiles` are super uncommon and take a little extra brain power to recall while reading.

```
bool try_again;
do {
    try_again = false;
    try {
        do_something();
    } catch( const std::exception& e) {
        std::cerr << e.what() << std::endl;
        try_again = true;
    }
} while (try_again);
```

The original `while` could be simplified with `break`, and this is probably the nicest variant of the loops, but it hurts if we need another little for-loop in there, or a switch statement.

```
while(true){
    try {
        do_something();
        break;
    } catch( const std::exception& e) {
        std::cerr << e.what() << std::endl;
    }
}
```

I would argue that the `goto` solution is clearer than both of those loops. Before posting, I barely caught a last-moment bug in my `do`/`while` loop. Another nice thing about the `goto` solution is if you do screw up with the label location, an error should occur:

```
try {
    try_again:
    do_something();
} catch (const std::exception& e) {
    std::cerr << e.what() << std::endl;
    goto try_again;
}
```

> error: cannot jump from this goto statement to its label
>
> note: jump bypasses initialization of try block